# Example of closed quantum system and open quantum system?

Tags: open-quantum-systems

A laser is an open system. From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_quantum_system,
I also know that clustering in nuclei is also treated as open quantum system.

Do closed quantum systems exist? If so, what is an example (e.g. strongly correlated electrons systems)?

Comment: There are no completely closed systems (not even in classical mechanics) because we need, at least, a classical measurement device connected to them to measure anything and that device is necessarily open. The difference between classical mechanics and quantum mechanics is simply that classically we can pretend that the measurement doesn't change the system. In QM we can't.

Comment: thank you very much for pointing out the measurement standpoint. Does measurement have to do with dissipation?

Comment: Based on all I know about it, which is not as much as I wish, measurement is invariable linked to some form of dissipation. That doesn't necessarily mean that we need a classical energy dissipating process (although almost invariable practical measurement setups have that). Think about the spatial separation between the quantum mechanical process (e.g. an atom) and a detector. Long before the detector has registered the photons coming from the atom, those photons had to spread into a much larger volume than that of the atom, so that's "dissipation", already.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of time scales. As pointed out by other answers and comments, there are no truly closed systems in Nature. However, it is possible in many experiments to describe the system adequately as closed, so long as the characteristic time scales of dissipation and decoherence are much longer than the time scales of interest. A modern example could be systems of trapped ultracold atoms, where experimentalists have become very skilled at eliminating sources of external noise over the time scales (seconds) relevant for the experiments. In this case, the evolution of the atoms can usually be predicted very well under the assumption of closed quantum system dynamics.